# Error in View when i try use inherit Linq magic

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql

I try make table where i keep children-parent data. Ofc root of parents is "0" and here in table can by many roots. When i try make this work i got error.

**Unable to create a constant value of type 'Projekty03.ViewsModels.ParagrafViewModel'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.**

```
    public ViewResult Index()
    {

        List<ParagrafViewModel> _paragrafparent = new List<ParagrafViewModel>();
        _paragrafparent.Add(new ParagrafViewModel { ParagrafID = 0, ParagrafNazwa = "Root" });

        var _paragrafparent2 = from pr in paragrafRepository.All
                               orderby pr.ParagrafID
                               select new ParagrafViewModel
                               {
                                   ParagrafID = pr.ParagrafID,
                                   ParagrafNazwa = pr.ParagrafNazwa
                               };

        var _paragrafparent3 = _paragrafparent.Concat(_paragrafparent2).AsEnumerable();

        var paragraf = from par in paragrafRepository.All
                       join rodzic_p in _paragrafparent3
                       on par.ParagrafParent equals rodzic_p.ParagrafID
                       orderby par.ParagrafParent, par.ParagrafID
                       select new ParagrafViewModel
                       {
                           ParagrafID = par.ParagrafID,
                           ParagrafNazwa = par.ParagrafNazwa,
                           ParagrafParent = par.ParagrafParent,
                           ParagrafCzynny = par.ParagrafCzynny,
                           ParagrafWplyw = par.ParagrafWplyw,
                           ParagrafParentNazwa = rodzic_p.ParagrafNazwa
                       };

        return View(paragraf);
    }
```

I believe is sht wrong with my poor magic LINQ think. How resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a answer for my own question. Im sure is not a pretty solution but ...

```
    public ViewResult Index()
    {

        List<ParagrafViewModel> _paragrafparent = new List<ParagrafViewModel>();
        _paragrafparent.Add(new ParagrafViewModel { ParagrafID = 0, ParagrafNazwa = "Root", ParagrafCzynny=false,  });

        var _paragrafparent2 = from pr in paragrafRepository.AllIncluding(paragraf => paragraf.WniosekPodzial)
                               orderby pr.ParagrafID
                               select new ParagrafViewModel
                               {
                                   ParagrafID = pr.ParagrafID,
                                   ParagrafNazwa = pr.ParagrafNazwa,
                                   ParagrafParent = pr.ParagrafParent,
                                   ParagrafCzynny = pr.ParagrafCzynny,
                                   ParagrafWplyw = pr.ParagrafWplyw,
                                   WniosekPodzialNazwa = pr.WniosekPodzial.WniosekPodzialNazwa
                               };

        var _paragrafparent3 = _paragrafparent.Concat(_paragrafparent2).AsEnumerable();

        var paragrafModel = from par in _paragrafparent3
                       join rodzic_p in _paragrafparent3
                       on par.ParagrafParent equals rodzic_p.ParagrafID
                       orderby par.ParagrafParent, par.ParagrafID
                       select new ParagrafViewModel
                       {
                           ParagrafID = par.ParagrafID,
                           ParagrafNazwa = par.ParagrafNazwa,
                           ParagrafParent = par.ParagrafParent,
                           ParagrafCzynny = par.ParagrafCzynny,
                           ParagrafWplyw = par.ParagrafWplyw,
                           ParagrafParentNazwa = rodzic_p.ParagrafNazwa,
                           WniosekPodzialNazwa = par.WniosekPodzialNazwa
                       };

        return View(paragrafModel);
    }
```